# C# Roslyn CompletionService where to get method overload information

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I've got a method that returning back from `CompletionService.GetDescriptionAsync(Document, CompletionItem)` gives me the following description:

```
void SQL.GetSQLiteDB(string url) (+ 1 overload)
```

This is a method I made on a Xamarin project, here are both method signatures:

```
public static void GetSQLiteDB(string url);
public static string GetSQLiteDB(string url, string name);
```

What's the Roslyn way to get information on both?

Here's how I'm setting up completions:

```
    async Task InitCodeCompletion()
    {
        host = MefHostServices.Create(MefHostServices.DefaultAssemblies);
        workspace = new AdhocWorkspace(host);

        Type[] types =
        {
            typeof(object),
            typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable),
            typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable),
            typeof(Console),
            typeof(System.Reflection.Assembly),
            typeof(List<>),
            typeof(Type),
            typeof(SQL)
        };

        imports = types.Select(x => x.Namespace).Distinct().ToImmutableArray();
        assemblies = types.Select(x => x.Assembly).Distinct().ToImmutableArray();
        references = assemblies.Select(t => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(t.Location) as MetadataReference).ToImmutableArray();

        compilationOptions = new CSharpCompilationOptions(
           OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,
           usings: imports);

        projectInfo = ProjectInfo.Create(ProjectId.CreateNewId(), VersionStamp.Create(), "Script", "Script", LanguageNames.CSharp, isSubmission: true)
           .WithMetadataReferences(references).WithCompilationOptions(compilationOptions);
        project = workspace.AddProject(projectInfo);
        documentInfo = DocumentInfo.Create(DocumentId.CreateNewId(project.Id), "Script", sourceCodeKind: SourceCodeKind.Script,
            loader: TextLoader.From(TextAndVersion.Create(SourceText.From(""), VersionStamp.Create())));
        document = workspace.AddDocument(documentInfo);

        var services = workspace.Services;

        completionService = CompletionService.GetService(document);
    }



    async Task<CodeCompletionResults> GetCompletions(string code)
    {
        string codeModified = "using SQL = XamTestNET5.Services.SQLiteGeneratorService; " + Environment.NewLine;
        codeModified += "using HtmlSvc = XamTestNET5.Services.HtmlRetrievalService;" + Environment.NewLine;
        // ^^^ The above two lines set up some simple namespace aliases in my project, if you know how to put this in a separate project document and use it in code completion please let me know in comments as otherwise doing so gives me an exception that you can't have multiple syntax trees
        codeModified += code;
        var source = SourceText.From(codeModified);
        document = document.WithText(source);

        // cursor position is at the end
        var position = source.Length;

        var completions = await completionService.GetCompletionsAsync(document, position);
        return new CodeCompletionResults() { InputCode = code, ModifiedCode = codeModified, Completions = completions }; 
    }
```

Here's how I'm getting them now and putting them in a browser control:

```
    private async void CSharpShellEnvironment_EntryCodeCompletionEntry(object sender, CSharpShellEnvironment.EntryEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != "")
        {
            CodeCompletionResults results = await GetCompletions(e.Value);
            CompletionList list = results.Completions;

            if (list != null)
            {
                if (list.Items != null)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var item in list.Items)
                    {
                        string spanText = (item.Span.Start != item.Span.End) ? results.ModifiedCode.Substring(item.Span.Start, item.Span.Length) : "";
                        bool recommended = spanText == "" ? true : item.DisplayText.StartsWith(spanText);
                        if (recommended)
                        {
                            string fText = item.DisplayText.Substring(spanText.Length);
                            string props = "";
                            foreach(var p in item.Properties)
                            {
                                props += $"<span data-key=\"{p.Key}\" data-value=\"{p.Value}\"></span>";
                            }
                            string tags = "";
                            foreach(var t in item.Tags)
                            {
                                tags += $"<span data-tag=\"{t}\"></span>";
                            }
                            string descStr = "";
                            if (item.Tags != null)
                            {
                                if (item.Tags.Where(x => x.ToLower() == "method").FirstOrDefault() != null && item.Tags.Where(x => x.ToLower() == "public").FirstOrDefault() != null)
                                {
                                    var desc = await completionService.GetDescriptionAsync(document, item);
                                    descStr += $"<span data-desc=\"{desc.Text}\">";
                                    foreach(var part in desc.TaggedParts)
                                    {
                                        descStr += $"<span data-desc-part-tag=\"{part.Tag}\" data-desc-part-text=\"{part.Text}\"></span>";
                                    }
                                    descStr += "</span>";
                                }
                            }
                            sb.AppendLine($"<div class=\"codecompleteentry\" data-display-text=\"{item.DisplayText}\" data-span-text=\"{spanText}\" data-final-text=\"{fText}\">{props}{tags}{descStr}{fText}</div>");
                        }
                    }
                    string scriptInputClick = "Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('codecompleteentry'), function(el) { el.addEventListener('click', function(elem) { var text = { MessageType: 'CodeCompletion', Parameters: JSON.stringify({ DataDisplayText: el.getAttribute('data-display-text'), DataSpanText: el.getAttribute('data-span-text'), DataFinalText: el.getAttribute('data-final-text') }), Message: el.innerText }; window.chrome.webview.postMessage(text); } ); });";
                    sb.AppendLine($"<script type=\"text/javascript\">{scriptInputClick}</script>");
                    env.EnterCodeCompletionResponse(sb.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    env.EnterCodeCompletionResponse(strNoSuggestions);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                env.EnterCodeCompletionResponse(strNoSuggestions);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            env.EnterCodeCompletionResponse(strNoSuggestions);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same question essentially, how to get all 17 overloads of Console.WriteLine in Roslyn?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: @Progman I added a minimal repro. There isn't a whole lot of documentation I can seem to find at all on this topic or any regarding Roslyn, other than looking at Roslyn sources on github and a small blog post, which I'll include along with some links to github sources.

Comment: Here are two places in the Roslyn source for GetDescriptionAsync() but both are marked as virtual, but where is the implementation? I need help finding that: 

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/afd10305a37c0ffb2cfb2c2d8446154c68cfa87a/src/Features/Core/Portable/Completion/CompletionService.cs#L148 also here https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/afd10305a37c0ffb2cfb2c2d8446154c68cfa87a/src/Features/Core/Portable/Completion/CompletionProvider.cs#L62

Comment: There's also this blog post which helped me get going on the topic, but I found GetDescriptionAsync() on my own and included in the repro above:

https://www.strathweb.com/2018/12/using-roslyn-c-completion-service-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

It seems on the surface that `CompletionSurface` has everything you need, but it doesn't, you need to reference the `Document`'s `SemanticModel` in order to get all of the signature overloads of a method when the user types `(` on a method during code completion.

It wasn't very obvious to me until I started looking through the RoslynPad source, which I recommend doing for a practical example: https://github.com/aelij/RoslynPad

```
    List<IEnumerable<ReferencedSymbol>> allMethodRefs = new List<IEnumerable<ReferencedSymbol>>();

    async Task<CodeCompletionResults> GetCompletions(string code)
    {
        string codeModified = "using SQL = XamTestNET5.Services.SQLiteGeneratorService; " + Environment.NewLine;
        codeModified += "using HtmlSvc = XamTestNET5.Services.HtmlRetrievalService;" + Environment.NewLine;
        // ^^^ I put my namespace aliases in the same SyntaxTree for now,
        //     I'd like a better solution though.
        codeModified += code;
        var source = SourceText.From(codeModified);
        document = document.WithText(source);

        // cursor position is at the end
        var position = source.Length;

        var completions = await completionService.GetCompletionsAsync(document, position);
        syntaxRoot = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
        semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync();
        var methods = syntaxRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();

        allMethodRefs = new List<IEnumerable<ReferencedSymbol>>();

        if (methods != null)
        {
            if (methods.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach(var m in methods)
                {
                    var info = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(m);
                    if (info.Symbol != null)
                    {
                        allMethodRefs.Add(await SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(info.Symbol, solution));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach(var symbol in info.CandidateSymbols)
                        {
                            allMethodRefs.Add(await SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(symbol, solution));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new CodeCompletionResults() { InputCode = code, ModifiedCode = codeModified, Completions = completions }; 
    }
```